# typescript array require atleast one object with property name and pull type of possible names

Tags: typescript

Sorry if the title is a little confusing.  Hopefully this will be clear.

I have a static defined object in code (Theme) that has a property called options which is an array.  In that array of options objects (ThemeOptions) I want to enforce atleast one of the objects has a property "themeName" that equals 'themedefault'.

```
interface ThemeOption {
  readonly themeName: string;
  readonly buttonColor: string;
  readonly textColor?: string;
  readonly backgroundColor?: string;
}

type ThemeOptionDefault = ThemeOption & {
  readonly themeName: 'themedefault';
}

type Theme = {
  id: string;
  label: string;
  options: readonly [ThemeOptionDefault, ...ReadonlyArray<ThemeOption>];
}

const changeThemes: Theme = {
  id: 'changeThemes',
  label: 'themeSwitcher',
  options: [
    {
      themeName: 'themedefault',
      buttonColor: '#ffffff',
      textColor: '#323332',
    },
    {
      themeName: 'theme2',
      buttonColor: '#ffffff',
      textColor: '#323332',
    },
  ] as const,
};
```

Now I want to export out a type that equals the string literal of possible options to use

```
type ChangeThemeNames = typeof changeThemes['options'][number]['themeName']
// type ChangeThemeNames = string // should be string[] but this is what intelisense infers
```

This is where I run into the problem.  This works as long as I dont declare `changeTheme` as `Theme`

```
const changeThemes = {
  id: 'changeThemes',
  label: 'themeSwitcher',
  options: [
    {
      themeName: 'themedefault',
      buttonColor: '#ffffff',
      textColor: '#323332',
    },
    {
      themeName: 'theme2',
      buttonColor: '#ffffff',
      textColor: '#323332',
    },
  ] as const,
};

// type ChangeThemeNames = "themedefault" | "theme2"
```

I understand this works because its being seen as a tuple.  My `readonly [ThemeOptionDefault, ...ReadonlyArray<ThemeOption>]` in the definition sets it as an array so it cannot become a string literal.

Is what I am trying to do possible?

I reuse this Theme in muliple places and have generic methods to work with them which is the idea behind this.  So if created I always want to have atleast one default theme and in the code have intelisense give me a dropdown for the possible values.

EDIT:

Current workout but still would like to have string literal from options on each.

```
type Theme = {
  readonly id: string;
  readonly label: string;
  readonly default: ThemeOptionDefault
  readonly options?: readonly ThemeOption[]
}
```

Comment: You need `as const satisfies Theme`

Comment: @Dimava do you want to write that up as an answer? (I'm not OP if it matters)

Comment: @Dimava, sorry I’m not following what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

based on @Dimava comment this is a solution to the problem

```
export interface ThemeOption {
  themeName: string;
  buttonColor: string;
  textColor?: string;
  backgroundColor?: string;
}

type ThemeOptionDefault = ThemeOption & {
  themeName: 'themedefault';
};

type Theme = {
  id: string;
  label: string;
  options: readonly [ThemeOptionDefault, ...ReadonlyArray<ThemeOption>];
};
```

```
const changeThemes = {
  id: 'changeThemes',
  label: 'themeSwitcher',
  options: [
    {
      themeName: 'themedefault',
      buttonColor: '#ffffff',
      textColor: '#323332',
    },
    {
      themeName: 'theme2',
      buttonColor: '#ffffff',
      textColor: '#323332',
    },
  ],
} as const satisfies Theme;
```

notice readonly is required to be put infront of the array on the Theme type